# Alternative command for show interface status

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-commands, packet-tracer

Is there any alternative command for `show interface status` on a switch?

In packet tracer (A simulation), `show interface status` is not working. However, in GNS3 and real Cisco switches this command will work fine. But, I'm using packet tracer and I want to get a quick overview of the entire device line status and details of each interfaces which is done by `show interface status` in real Cisco device. So, is there anyway to do this in packet tracer?

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Port      Name      Status    Vlan    Duplex   Speed   Type
------------------------------------------------------------------
Fa0/1             connected   1       full     auto    0/100BaseTX
Fa0/2             notconnect  1       auto     auto    0/100BaseTX
Fa0/3             notconnect  1       auto     auto    0/100BaseTX
```

[image: Screenshot of packet tracer]

Thanks!

Comment: As you said, that command does not exist on packet tracer. The only command I can suggest to you would be "show ip interface brief" which will not show you the speeds though. This is mainly used to display ip addresses assigned to layer 3 ports. Alternatively you just need to use "show interface" and view all the details of the port. But with "show ip interface brief", it will at least show you the status.

Comment: Thank you SleepyMan. "show interface" shows the all the information I need. But It's hard to read. Using the two commands you gave me, I should be able to do the job. Thanks again.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you said, that command does not exist on packet tracer. The only
>   command I can suggest to you would be "show ip interface brief" which
>   will not show you the speeds though. This is mainly used to display ip
>   addresses assigned to layer 3 ports. Alternatively, you just need to
>   use "show interface" and view all the details of the port. But with
>   "show ip interface brief", it will at least show you the status. –
>   SleepyMan

Packet Tracer does not support this command yet. (v7.1.1).

Packet Tracer is a simulator and it comes with some limitations. It does not run all commands that run in real Switches or Routers.

GNS3 is an alternative to Packet Tracer and it supports this commands.
Try GNS3: [https://www.gns3.com](https://gns3.com)

> **What is GNS3?**
>
> GNS3 allows you to visualize, plan, test and troubleshoot network
>   environments across any vendor platform at scale - without the need to
>   directly interact with the network hardware. With the intuitive
>   graphical interface, users can seamlessly connect all types of virtual
>   interfaces to compose a real representation of networks. GNS3 runs on
>   traditional PC hardware and may be used on multiple operating systems,
>   including Windows, Linux, and MacOS X.
>
> **What is the difference between an emulator and a simulator?**
>
> An emulator will run an exact copy of an actual network operating
>   system. A simulator is designed to have a resemblance to the actual
>   network operating system, but only 'simulate' functions. GNS3
>   Ironically has 'simulator' in its acronym, but it simulates entire
>   networks, not just network operating systems. Most users use GNS3 to
>   emulate Cisco IOS as well as other vendors. But what sets GNS3 apart
>   from other simulators, is its ability to EMULATE routing and switching
>   as well as incorporate REAL virtual machines and connect them together
>   via a logical tunneling system (overlay network). That is why it is
>   better to say where other software SIMULATE, GNS3 has made advances to
>   EMULATE your real production networks.
>
> **What is the difference between GNS3 and Packet Tracer / VIRL?**
>
> Packet Tracer and VIRL are Cisco's offerings and answers to the
>   advancement of GNS3's advanced EMULATION. There are strengths and
>   weaknesses to each product, but GNS3 is first in Emulating real
>   production networks. For more information attached are some recent
>   articles written on the comparison: Cisco VIRL vs. GNS3 - How They
>   Compare - GlobalConfig.net (Un)Biased review of someone who used VIRL

Reference: https://gns3.com/software/faq

Comment: Adding onto DT's answer, you need to realize that GNS3 is difficult to configure and will require you to have the actual IOS software for each router or switch you want to use. I want to use GNS3 badly but it is sluggish compared to PT and takes a lot of time to get setup properly. I spent a good bit of time trying to get IOS configs to load and everything was unsupported except a few new routers / switches. 2811 wasnt supported, 3560 wasnt, etc.